Getting undefined (reading 'toString') in ng-apexcharts hovering on legend
i was using ng-apexcharts(^1.9.0) & apexcharts(^3.45.1). and it was working fine & deployed in production. After few months i create a branch from master(deployed in prod) but i am getting below console error hovering on legend. Same code same version no changes, still getting issue. can someone please help me with this ??
(https://i.sstatic.net/xVF5Slji.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/xVF5Slji.png)
I have tried with different version of ng-apexcharts and apexcharts, but getting same error.
click here & hover on legend you can see the error in console thanks.

Possible that is it due to your data being incorrect? Have you checked on it? Would be great to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Looks like the object is undefined check if the object is defined before toString() is called.

Hi @Youg Shun, i updated, i gave one link please check that. Thanks.
